# ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 2 al abrir archivo CSV con Python

Tags: python, csv

He comenzado recientemente a utilizar python y otros lenguajes de programación, para poder manejar datos relacionados con la agricultura, que es mi sector.

Estoy realizando un script que me hace un web scrapping de una base de datos climáticos del gobierno, descargándose los mismos en un archivo zip que contiene un csv. Una vez se descarga el archivo, cierra el navegador, posteriormente me guarda el último archivo descargado en una carpeta y le pone un nombre conocido, descomprime el archivo zip y después le cambia el nombre al CSV guardándolo en otra carpeta. A continuación muestro el código una vez ha cerrado el navegador hasta que intento abrir el archivo CSV.

```py
filename = max(['C:/Users/jose luis/Downloads' +'/'+ f for f in os.listdir('C:/Users/jose luis/Downloads')], key=os.path.getctime)
shutil.move(os.path.join('C:/Users/jose luis',filename),'SIAR2.zip')

time.sleep(2)

#Descomprimimos el archivo zip que esta ahora en la carpeta spyder

archivo_zip = shutil.unpack_archive('C:/Users/jose luis/.spyder-py3/SIAR2.zip','C:/Users/jose luis')

time.sleep(2)

#Le damos un nombre conocido al archivo CSV con el que trabajaremos finalmente

filename = max(['C:/Users/jose luis' +'/'+ f for f in os.listdir('C:/Users/jose luis')], key=os.path.getctime)
df = shutil.move(os.path.join('C:/Users/jose luis/.spyder-py3',filename),'Dato.csv')

Dat = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/jose luis/.spyder-py3/Dato.csv')
```

Intento abrir dicho archivo, pero da siempre el siguiente error

```text
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 2
```

He intentado varias formas de abrirlo, entre ellas que me pusiera el delimitador en `;` y los decimales en `,` pero me sigue ocurriendo el mismo error, también he intentado pasarlo a xlsx y pero también me daba error.

A continuación muestro el archivo CSV en texto

```text
IdProvincia;IdEstacion;Fecha;Año;Dia;HoraMin;Temp Media (ºC)
22;7;10/11/2018;2018;314;30;8,54
22;7;10/11/2018;2018;314;100;8,16
22;7;10/11/2018;2018;314;130;8,61
22;7;10/11/2018;2018;314;200;8,77
22;7;10/11/2018;2018;314;230;9,71
22;7;10/11/2018;2018;314;300;8,47
22;7;10/11/2018;2018;314;330;8,34
22;7;10/11/2018;2018;314;400;7,89
22;7;10/11/2018;2018;314;430;7,67
22;7;10/11/2018;2018;314;500;7,47
22;7;10/11/2018;2018;314;530;7,72
22;7;10/11/2018;2018;314;600;7,07
```

He intentado abrirlo con pandas también utilizando el siguiente código

```py
df2 = pd.read_csv("Dato.csv", delimiter=';')
 
print(df2)
```

Pero me da como resultado un dataframe con valores nulos

```text
I  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3  Unnamed: 4  Unnamed: 5  Unnamed: 6
0   NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
1   NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2   NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
3   NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
4   NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
..   ..         ...         ...         ...         ...         ...         ...
573 NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
574 NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
575 NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
576 NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
577 NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN

[578 rows x 7 columns]
```

Adjunto el script completo que hace también el web scrapping, para ver si hubiera algún error en el mismo que no me permite eer el csv en python. El código es el siguiente:

```
print('Iniciando Scraper')
import zipfile
import os
import selenium
import selenium.webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select 
from zipfile import ZipFile
import shutil
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

#Entrar en la web del SIAR y meter usuario y contaseña
opts = Options()

opts.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36")

driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=opts)

LOGIN_URL = driver.get('https://eportal.mapa.gob.es/portal/site/eportal/template.LOGIN/')

URL = "https://eportal.mapa.gob.es//websiar/Inicio.aspx"

user = '*'

password = '*'


input_user = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="username"]')))
input_pass = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="password"]')

input_user.send_keys(user)
input_pass.send_keys(password)

#Pulsar botón entrar

boton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@value="Entrar"]')

boton.click()

#Pulsar botón WEBSIAR

boton_SIAR = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="hM_94e0c0807a65a3338c1238c184dc20a0"]')


boton_SIAR.click()

#Pulsar botón Ir Aplicación

boton_Ir = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@value="Ir Aplicación"]')

boton_Ir.click()


#Pulsar boton Consultas Avanzadas

boton_CAv = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="LinkButtonConsultasAvanzadas"]')

boton_CAv.click()

#Selección de CCAA, prov y parámetros

 # Comundad  autónoma
 
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ContentPlaceHolder1_DropDownListCCAA'))
select.select_by_value('1')


time.sleep(2)

# Provincia
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('DropDownListProvincia'))
select.select_by_value('23')


time.sleep(2)

value_est=2 # Estación
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('DropDownListEstacion'))
select.select_by_value('16')

time.sleep(5)

agregar_estacion = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ButtonAgregar"]')
click_agregar_estacion = agregar_estacion.click()

time.sleep(0.5)

driver.find_element_by_id('txtFechaIni').clear() # Borra la fecha de inicio por…

time.sleep(0.5)

driver.find_element_by_id('txtFechaFin').clear() # Borra la fecha fin por defecto…

time.sleep(2)

imputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("txtFechaIni")
imputElement.send_keys('1/09/2021') # Fecha de Inicio

time.sleep(2)

imputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("txtFechaFin")
imputElement.send_keys('2/09/2021') # Fecha de Fin

time.sleep(2)

añadir_temp =  driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[id="ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBoxTemp"]')
añadir_temp.click()

time.sleep(2)

consultar_datos_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[id="ContentPlaceHolder1_btnConsultar"]')
consultar_datos = consultar_datos_button.click()

time.sleep(2)

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
exportar_csv_link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ExportarCSV"]')
descargar_csv = exportar_csv_link.click()

time.sleep(2)


driver.quit() #Cierra el navegador

time.sleep(2)


filename = max(['C:/Users/jose luis/Downloads' +'/'+ f for f in os.listdir('C:/Users/jose luis/Downloads')], key=os.path.getctime)
shutil.move(os.path.join('C:/Users/jose luis',filename),'SIAR2.zip')

time.sleep(2)

#Descomprimimos el archivo zip que esta ahora en la carpeta spyder

archivo_zip = shutil.unpack_archive('C:/Users/jose luis/.spyder-py3/SIAR2.zip','C:/Users/jose luis')

time.sleep(2)

#Le damos un nombre conocido al archivo CSV con el que trabajaremos finalmente

filename = max(['C:/Users/jose luis' +'/'+ f for f in os.listdir('C:/Users/jose luis')], key=os.path.getctime)
df = shutil.move(os.path.join('C:/Users/jose luis/.spyder-py3',filename),'Dato.csv')



import pandas as pd

Dat = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/jose luis/.spyder-py3/Dato.csv',sep=';')

    
print (Dat)
```

Comment: Bienvenido Jos Luis Garca-Palacios Faure a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Por favor agrega a tu pregunta un ejemplo del CSV, unas pocas líneas en formato texto. Usa el botón "editar".

Comment: Agrega tambien a tu pregunta el codigo pyhton usado que dices que has intentado, sino vamos a ciegas.

Comment: Algo no cuadra. El csv tiene 7 columnas y la tabla que muestra pandas tiene 6. ¿Estás seguro que no lees otro fichero csv que el que muestras?

Comment: Con total seguridad lee el fichero que os muestro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Respuesta editada:**

En la respuesta anterior se solucionaba este error:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 2
```

pero de hecho el OP ya lo habia solucionado  `delimiter=';'`, pues parece ser que son lo mismo.

### Solución al problema de NaN y Undefined en la función read_csv() de pandas

El problema puede venir dado por codificación del archivo distinta a la que la función `read_csv` espera, por lo tanto hay que indicarle que [codificación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) tiene.

Se puede conocer la codificación del archivo escribiendo esto en terminal:

```
file Dato.csv
```

que nos va a devolver su codificación, por ejemplo:

```
Dato.csv: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

En este caso, ésta codificación es aceptada sin problemas y no hay que hacer nada más. Pero en caso contrario hay que indicarle a la función `read_csv` la [codificación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) correcta. Por ejemplo, si el archivo tuviera la codificacion `UTF16 LE`, entonces la instrucción seria esta:

```
pd.read_csv("Dato.csv", sep=";", encoding='UTF-16 LE')
```

Y con esto deberia arreglarse el problema.

---

**Respuesta anterior:**

Prueba poniendo el separador en `;` en la instrucción `read_csv` mediante `,sep=';'`.

Así:

```
Dat = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/jose luis/.spyder-py3/Dato.csv',sep=';')
```

A mi ha funcionado con el trozo de CSV que has puesto en la pregunta.

Por defecto `read_csv` de **pandas** solo busca comas `,` como separador de columnas.

Si le fuerzo la salida con `print(Dat.head(5))` me aparece esto:

```
   IdProvincia  IdEstacion       Fecha   Año  Dia  HoraMin Temp Media (ºC)
0           22           7  10/11/2018  2018  314       30            8,54
1           22           7  10/11/2018  2018  314      100            8,16
2           22           7  10/11/2018  2018  314      130            8,61
3           22           7  10/11/2018  2018  314      200            8,77
4           22           7  10/11/2018  2018  314      230            9,71
```

El código usado ha sido esto (ejecutándolo con Python3):

```
import pandas as pd
Dat = pd.read_csv('/ruta/Dato.csv',sep=';')
print(Dat.head(5))
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta @masterguru, he utilizado el código que me has indicado y me abre el csv pero no me aparecen los valores del mismo, devuelve  las columnas como 'Unnamed' y los valores como 'Nan'. Tal que así:         I  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  ...  Unnamed: 4  Unnamed: 5  Unnamed: 6
0     NaN         NaN         NaN  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN
1     NaN         NaN         NaN  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN

Comment: @JosLuisGarca-PalaciosFaure ¿Y el contenido del csv es exactamente el mismo? ¿Lo has probado con este trozo que has puesto en la pregunta solamente? ¿Si abres Dato.csv con un editor ves lo mismo? ¿Usas la misma version de python? (yo no supe instalar pandas en la 2.7)

Comment: Por cierto, no lo he mencionado, pero estoy utilizando spyder 4.1.4. No  sé si esto interfiere

Comment: Nunca he usado spyder, la verdad, simplemente lo ejecuto desde un terminal con `python3 script.py` donde `script.py` contiene el código que he puesto

Comment: Usando el código en jupyter me devuelve la misma salida que con spyder. Voy a probar a descargarme python 3

Comment: @JosLuisGarca-PalaciosFaure Me acabo de instalar el spyder (version 3) y su consola me muestra lo mismo, es decir, me lo muestra bien

Comment: @JosLuisGarca-PalaciosFaure ¿Cual es tu version de python?  Escribe python -v a ver que te sale... y estas en windows, linux, mac?... de paso escribe `python3 -v` tambien, quizas ya lo tienes instalado (pueden coexistir varias version de python en un mismo sistema)

Comment: Mi versión de python es la 3.8.3

Comment: @JosLuisGarca-PalaciosFaure Pues deberia funcionarte... ¿has mirado si el Dato.csv es identico con los mismos registros que has pegado en la pregunta?

Comment: Es idéntico, por eso me extraña. Voy a subir el script entera que hace el web scrapping por si hubiera algún error en este

Comment: Muchas gracias por vuestra paciencia y ayuda

Comment: @JosLuisGarca-PalaciosFaure: Si el Dato.csv es identico entonces algo debes tener mal en tu python3, y no se lo que es... acabo de probarlo en un editor online y funciona bien tambien... ¿no tienes otra maquina donde probar?

Comment: @JosLuisGarca-PalaciosFaure: Míralo tu mismo aquí: https://www.online-python.com/jxsnWrkScd  (he tenido que adaptarlo un poco, pero basicamente es lo mismo)

Comment: @JosLuisGarca-PalaciosFaure: Quizás la codificación del archivo tenga que ver, he encontrado uno que lo arregló pasandole el parametro equivalente a la codificacion del archivo que tenia, así:  `pd.read_csv("ADSearch.txt",encoding='UTF-16 LE')`... Si estas en linux o mac escribe `file Dato.csv` para que te diga que codificacion tiene y a ver si es eso

Comment: @JosLuisGarca-PalaciosFaure: O abre el Dato.csv con el spyder y mira abajo a la derecha que valor te pone en "Encoding:"... a mi me pone UTF-8

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @Mastergurú!! Has dado en el clavo!! Efectivamente era un problema de la codificación, se pasa a la codificación que se tiene y se le pone como separador ';' y queda arreglado. Quedaría por tanto así: `pd.read_csv("ADSearch.txt",sep = ';', encoding='UTF-16 LE')`

Comment: @JosLuisGarca-PalaciosFaure Acabo de cambiar la respuesta, mira si ahora cuadra con lo que hemos hecho y si es asi ya puedes darla por aceptada, y sino me lo dices y la cambio de nuevo